# Looping through JavaScript in order to have pagination in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, infinite-scroll

I'm sure this is a simple fix for a lot of you. I'm using ngInfinitescroll and looking to set up the pagenation. I'm new to JS and probably in over my head, but looking to see if I'm on the right track.

```
  .factory('Infinite', function($http) {
  var Infinite = function() {
    this.items = [];
    this.page = '';
  };

    Infinite.prototype.nextPage = function() {

      var url = "/api/v1/activity.json?page=" + this.page + "&?channel_id=2165604";
      $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
        var items = data;
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
          this.page(page[i]);
        }
        this.page = i;
      }.bind(this));
    };

    return Infinite;
  })
```

The goal here is to try and get pagination set up in oder to automatically call a new set of 10 items.  I'm sure I'm just missing something very easy, but I get "ReferenceError: page is not defined"  Would this set up even work with how nginfinitescroll is set up?

http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html

I tried to base this off their reddit example, but for our API I really just need it incremental by 1 for every page.

http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html

Comment: Hmm well the loop makes no sense since you could just say var i=0 or just replace i with 0 everywhere since the initialization and condition in the loop will always keep the value at 0 (rather 1 for the this.page = i portion).

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Am I not saying that if i is less then 1 then just keep adding +1 to i?

Comment: Indeed you are but you are starting i at 0, then it looks like calling a function call page on this object passing page[0], the end of that iteration happens, it increments i to 1, then it breaks out of the loop and does this.page = 1;  since it will always have this behavior, there is no reason to have that loop it can be easily "unrolled" so it just says this.page(page[0]); this.page=1, though in all honesty it doesn't make much sense because this.page is being treated as a function and as an integer.

Comment: Ah, So I'm not really making this.page go up as by one as a value.  I'm just going up by one and then telling it to stop right away.  That makes sense.  I really want to have this.page be set at 0 and then have page go up by 1 each time.  This makes more sense.

Comment: Yup to increment use ++ so this.page++ will increment the page by 1 assuming you start it at 0 this should work fine I think you'd want to pull that bit of code up above the call to get the data though because you want to first increment the page your going to get then get it.

Comment: Gotcha.  I'll give it all a go and see what I come up with.

Comment: So now I think I've got closer to what I need.  I refactored things a bit and I'm ending up with